# Change the format of a string inside a sed statment

Tags: bash, sed

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
<cell decimals="3" number="0.99916218350572" text=",999"/>
```

and I want to change it to

```
<cell decimals="3" number="9.991622E-01" text=",999"/>
```

I'm new to bash. After having researched and experimented, I have gotten to

```
cat myXMLfile | sed "s/\(number\=\)\(\"[0-9]*[\.\][0-9]*[\-]*e*\-*[0-9]*\)/number\=\2/g"
```

but \2 isn't the formatted value. I want the value stored in \2 to be formatted as in "printf %.6E".

Sorry for my ignorance in this area and thanks in advance for helping me learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
> s='<cell decimals="3" number="0.99916218350572" text=",999"/>'
> awk -F '"' '{$4=sprintf("%.6E", $4)} 1' OFS='"' <<< "$s"
<cell decimals="3" number="9.991622E-01" text=",999"/>
```

Comment: That looks like it will do the job. Thanks very much!